# if i charge my laptop every 10 minutes while playing will it kill damage the battery?

Tags: battery, gaming

i'm playing a gain but my battery drains fast. If I charge my laptop while playing it gets bery hot/loud and freezes. If i charge my laptop every 10 minutes while playing will it kill damage the battery?

Comment: You should see why the game is causing this issue, and also what else is heating up the laptop. Heat like this is not normal. Charging for 10 minutes and then not, over and over again will weaken the battery.

Comment: By your description, I think that the battery is already dying.

Comment: "Charging for 10 minutes and then not, over and over again will weaken the battery" Actually not true at all. It is the deep discharge/charge that damages them the most.

Comment: thanks for the replies, it's a game that isn't completely finished yet and uses a lot of resources, but my laptop's battery has always lasted two hours while playing other games, and about six while not

Comment: I would look to see what your game is doing with respect to CPU usage and driving it to very high usage.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds as if your battery is going bad.
Because of that it drains fast and it gets very hot while draining.
Combined with the load of the game, that also creates heat, things get too hot and the loud fan kicks in. (And if it gets too hot your laptop freezes.)
Doing this short charge/discharge cycle combined with the heat actually degrades the battery even faster, so it makes your problem even worse.
And: Running very hot often/for long periods of time is also not good for the rest of the laptop.

Can you remove the battery and run the laptop directly on mains power? That is usually possible and should deal with both your problems: It prevents the excessive heating and wear on the battery and the loud noise.

Most laptops have a diagnostic utility (software or in the Bios) to do a diagnostic on the battery. If it is bad consider replacing it.
Be advised that these batteries can be very expensive and if you have an older laptop that is getting slow/outdated anyway it may make more sense to replace the entire laptop then investing more money into this laptop.

P.S. Also make sure the cooling fan and exhaust in the laptop are not clogged with dust. That may be partially the cause of running very hot.